# Help me understand this treeview query

Tags: c#, .net

```
this.treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
bool my_node_exists = this.treeView.Nodes.Contains(node);
TreeNode[] my_nodes = this.treeView.Nodes.Find(node.Text, true);
```

Here, `my_node_exists` is `true`, but `my_nodes` is empty.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are confuzzling, it uses the term "name" and "key" interchangeably.  The Find() method finds node by key, not the node text.  Be sure to set it when you add the node.  This works:

```
        treeView1.Nodes.Add("aardvark", "Eats ants");
        TreeNode[] nodes = treeView1.Nodes.Find("aardvark", true);
        Debug.Assert(nodes.Length > 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs of [`TreeNodeCollection.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it returns:

> An array of TreeNode objects whose Name property matches the specified key

You're passing in the `Text` property - so unless the node's name happens to be the same as its text, it *wouldn't* find that node.

If you need to find a node by its text, I think you'll have to iterate over all the nodes recursively and test each one yourself.

Comment: @Schultz9999: Not at all. I have no formal relationship with Stack Overflow Internet Services Inc. I just enjoy answering questions :)

Comment: @Schultz9999: Yeah, but Nick Craver's average over the last ~9 months is way higher. Now that he's been hired by Stack Overflow, I'm hoping they'll keep him busy ;)

Comment: @Jon: well, all the best. Keep doing great job.

Comment: I want Jon to send me a lock of his hair for coding guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that you are using two different representations of the tree? The first one is using TreeNode based but the Find call relies on (key,text). In your example you never set a key for the node. Is TreeView class smart enough to use node.Text as a key?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Name property of the Node to Find IT.

```
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode("data");
        this.treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
        bool a = this.treeView.Nodes.Contains(node);
        int count = this.treeView.Nodes.Count;
        TreeNode[] nodess = this.treeView.Nodes.Find(node.Name, false);
```